# difference between ldrex/strex and swp

Tags: arm

difference between ldrex/strex and swp
What is the diff

do they have same function

is one better than other how?
As per arm v7 rm

ARM strongly recommends that all software uses the synchronization primitives described in this section, rather than SWP or SWPB.

Comment: swp does not fit well in a multi-core architecture, thus the push to use ldrex/strex instead.  You need hardware support from the chip vendor in order for ldrex/strex to work properly, not sure who manages swp off hand, if arm manages it then it is less risky for a single core/uniprocessor, but as arm has indicated it will go away eventually.

Answer (score 3):

`SWP` simply does exactly what its name suggests - swaps the contents of a register with a word in memory atomically, and nothing else. It's deprecated since v6, may not be present in some v7 implementations and is removed from the architecture entirely in v8 (similarly `SWPB`, the single-byte version).

[Load/store exclusives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) on the other hand are primitives out of which you can construct just about any [atomic read-modify-write operation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h). The other key point of exclusives is that they are non-blocking, so better suited to multiprocessor environments - if CPU1 writes to the same address in the middle of CPU0's atomic operation, CPU0 will see the `STREX` fail and simply retry, whilst CPU1 is none the wiser. Compare that to bus-locked atomics, in which CPU1 would be prevented from accessing *any* memory at all until CPU0 has finished.

Answer (score 0):

A key difference is that `swp` and `swpb` are more performant on a single core CPU.  The CPU implementation must lock the entire bus to do the *read-modifiy-write* cycle.  During this time, a DMA device can not access the *gasket* or *memory port* of the main memory.  In the case of multi-core devices this can significantly impact performance as it is not just DMA devices, but all other cores.

With `ldrex/strex`, it can piggy back on cache logic dirty/clean mechanics to reserve a portion of memory for update and it can later be confirmed as correctly committed much like a spin-lock.  It is definitely more complex and often people will cite that `swp` is easier to use.  However, on newer multi-core systems (v6,v7,v8), the `swp` has a high system performance penalty.  It should be clearly understood as a difference between the two.  This is the rational of why ARM wants to deprecate `swp`.

For lock free programming, this is only needed for multiple writers (producers).  You can use simple FIFO (ring buffers) for single producers and memory ordering is the only significant difficulty.